# Phrase like "in recent memory", but opposite of "recent", i.e. "since forever"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I distinctly remember encountering a phrase of the form

> in {???} memory

with meaning opposite to "in recent memory", i.e. "since forever", but I can't recall what adjective went in the {???} slot.

It's *not* ***"since time immemorial"***.

Comment: In what context did you encounter it?

Comment: I don't remember. I just want to say something like "This is the most buggy release of CoolSoftwareSuite™ in {???} memory", i.e. "not even the oldest Native elders remember a more buggy one". I am sure I have encountered a phrase exactly like that, I just forgot the adjective.

Comment: "Since forever" is not English. See my comment on the answer you wrongly accepted.

Comment: You can express the idea in the context you give by "that anyone can remember". or just "in memory".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You may be thinking of

> *since **living** memory* ([Power Thesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/since_living_memory))

Comment: Yes, "within living memory", that's the one!

Comment: Note that "within living memory" means [_during a time that can be remembered by people who are still alive_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%2Fwithin%20living%20memory).

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski Living memory is definitely **not** "since forever"; *that* is "since time immemorial," because no-one can remember since forever. "In living memory" means that people **do** remember it, even though it may be in the dim and distant past.

Comment: "**Since** living memory" is not English, a language in which "since" is always used with a fixed time point, unlike French and German. The Thesaurus may have humoured your request, but if you do a general Google search all you'll get is "in/within" living memory.

Comment: @David Is "since forever" a fixed time point? "Since living memory" may not be common, but [it is used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=since+living+memory&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: No.  Nor is it English. As I have commented to the poster. It may be a recent "humorous" expression used in some quarters. The same idea is expressed simply by "forever". An equivalent expression with "since" is "since the dawn of time".

Comment: @David i agree that the accepted answer is incorrect. “Living memory” refers to an extended period of time and is not a particular instant in time. “Since” applies to a particular time. The two do not combine. An alternative such as “In living memory” is an acceptable phrase.

Comment: The accepted answer works for me (the OP) in the specific figurative sense for which I needed it.

Comment: The point of answering is to give good advice. If a questioner feels they know better than a number of respondents, it is hard to understand why they bothered asking.